# У меня видео заслоняет фото текст и аудио

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/positionBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remainingTimeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The end" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/download_video_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="230dp"/>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/download_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/download_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:textColor="#D50000"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: слишком мало информации чтобы дать хоть какой-то ответ

Comment: Простите вам еще что нужно я думал что этого будет достаточно

Answer (score 1):

Перенеси `</LinearLayout>` в конец разметки.

Comment: Она не помогает если я перенесу то выстраиваются в один ряд. Спасибо